# UITableViewController subclass setEditing: never puts the tableView in editing mode

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using a SplitViewController and Core Data.  My Master view is a simple TableView like the SplitViewController template.  I have these three methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        [self saveContext];
    }   
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

I thought this would be enough to show the delete button when I swipe the row to delete it.  What happens now is if you swipe it the first time and only the first time, the delete button shows up then disappears.  If I swipe again, nothing happens.  I need to restart the simulator in order for it to show again.  On my TableViewCell, I have a UILabel and a UITextField.  I thought maybe the UITextField would be intercepting the swipe, but I resized them so they are only on the left half just in case.

Edit:

So I still haven't figured out why this happens.  I thought I would add an edit button to test if the tableView setEditing: even gets called.  So in my action method, I do:

```
- (IBAction)setEditMode:(id)sender {
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This method does get called, but the tableView never gets in editing mode.  All of this is in a subclass of UITableViewController.  Is there something else i'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: may i know that, Is splitView Controller will work in iphone???

Comment: @venkat SplitViewController does not work on iPhone, only iPad

Comment: you have added the iphone tag in this question... thats y i askd...

Comment: @venkat sorry, force of habit for all ios related question.  My mistake.

Comment: its ok... just clarification only...

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

        //Delete the object from the table.
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```